# PHP json_encode() Results In HTTP 500

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP 5.3.3 array that I need to `json_encode`; encoding fails and Apache returns an HTTP 500.

The array contains `Snort` rules; until recently the database contained about 700 rules and, the other day, about 10000 rules were added.  That's when the web application broke.  The application retrieves the data via PHP JSON-encoded so I `json_decode` then go through a `foreach` loop to "restructure" the data into a new, temporary array.  As a part of building the new array I `htmlentities` (with `ENT_QUOTES`) the "options" part of the Snort rule (otherwise I have browser display issues).  Once the new array is complete I...

```
$data = json_encode(array_values($temp));
```

...which is where my code used to work but is now failing.

If you're not familiar with Snort rules, examples of the options part of a rule are:

```
flow:established,to_server; content:"?sid="; http_uri; pcre:"/\?sid=[0-9A-F]{180}/U"; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2007142; classtype:trojan-activity;
```

...and...

```
flow:established,to_server; content:"|00 00 00 83|"; depth:4; content:"<CPU>"; content:"</CPU><"; distance:0; content:"<MEM>"; content:"</MEM><"; distance:0; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/bin/view/Main/TrojanDropper497; classtype:trojan-activity;
```

PHP documentation for json_encode notes data must be UTF-8 which mine is (ASCII according to `mb_detect_encoding()`).  I have seen other JSON posts with HTTP 500 issues.  Many are unrelated to my problem though there was one which caught my attention and was easy to rule out... I added `set_time_limit` even though this didn't seem to be the issue.  The failure occurs very promptly.

I'm not sure what else to do to troubleshoot.

Your expertise is much appreciated.

Thanks.

=== EDIT ===
The code, with new data, works in a dev environment.

Dev (works)
* Apache/2.2.8
* PHP 5.2.5

Prod (doesn't work)
* Apache/2.4.2
* PHP 5.5.3

Comment: Do you get any output in your PHP log?

Comment: Php.ini has `error_log` commented out.  Supposing I can get that change approved, it will take a week.  Apache logs did not help.

Comment: Do you have any way of testing the same data set locally? This is pure guesswork but it might be that now you have 10,000 rules the script may be exceeding the allowed memory limit. See this page for a bit more info about that: http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/14/increase-php-memory-limit/

Comment: The same data and code works in a dev instance of the app... adding more info to question...

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` is also only applying heuristics. I'd rather use `mb_check_encoding()` with either UTF-8, or (if you want to restrict yourself to that) with ASCII.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey: Submit a memory solution for me to accept... I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` which allowed the code to complete.  I should have checked that since I had already run into the same problem on another page (but affected *both* dev and prod).  Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Comment: /me wishes dev and prod were the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the error started when more records were added, my suspicion is the script was now using too much memory. Perhaps the memory limit is lower in production than it is in development.

Solutions for this are documented here: http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/14/increase-php-memory-limit/

Comment: Added `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` to my code which solved the problem.  Thanks Dave.